# play .mov file in UIWebView

Tags: ios, html, redirect, uiwebview, mov

I have a `.mov` file in my backend servers. I want to play this in `UIWebView` instance. This is how i am doing it using HTML5

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<video src='%@' controls autoplay height='480' width='640'> </video>",[mediaUrl absoluteString]];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

The thing is `mediaUrl` hits an API on my backend servers which does a HTTP redirect to the `.mov` file. This is not working in `UIWebView`. How do i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you don't want to use MPMoviePlayerViewController?

Comment: `MPMoviePlayerViewController` does not seem to handle redirect urls either. its crashing. what are my options here?